# Get the citations of a given patent programmatically from lens.org

Tags: citation

Using a web browser, I can manually get the citations of a given patent using lengs.org as follows:

1. Visit: https://www.lens.org/lens/search?q=US7723099B2&preview=true
2. Click "Cited Works"
   For each publication, get the title and DOI.

Does lens.org have an API to do so programmatically?

Does the [PatSeq Bulk Download API](https://support.lens.org/patseq-bulkdownload-apidoc/) give access to this data?

Any other idea to achieve the same objective?

Comment: Have attempted to actually ask The Lens? https://about.lens.org/contact-us/